# Php giving 2 possible form action for one button

Tags: php, if-statement, submit

I have this button, I want to make it link to different forms depending on a condition. Here is what I've tried

```
<?php
        if($lessons=null){
            ?>
            <form action="create.php" method="post">
                <?php }
        else{
            ?>
            <form action="k1levelselect.php" method="post">
                <?php }

        ?>

        <input type="submit" value="K1"
```

$lessons is a column in my table. If lessons has no value, I want to go to 'create.php' to add lessons, else i want to go straight to k1levelselect.php. But it brings me to k1levelselect.php no matter whether my table column is empty or not. Am I implementing my if else statement wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you current code, you are using the assignment operator:

```
if($lessons=null){ // using =
```

you must use the `==` comparison operator:

```
if($lessons==null){ // must be like this
```

Alternatively, you could also use a short-hand if (ternary) on this case:

```
<form action="<?php echo ($lessons == null) ? 'create.php' : 'k1levelselect'; ?>" method="post">
```

How to check:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$query = $db->query('SELECT `lessons` FROM `lessonno`');
$results = $query->fetch_assoc();
$lessons = $results['lessons'];
```

Comment: When I use the first method you suggested. It says 'Notice: Undefined variable: lessons' But I've already connected my database, why does it say my 'lessons' is undefined?

Comment: @Chunkeat is `$lessons` defined? it says its undefined? from fetching the value from the database, set `$lessons` accordingly

Comment: I did this, 
$lessons = isset($_POST['lessons']) ? $_POST['lessons'] : '';
Is it correct?

Comment: @Chunkeat oh so this is from a form, then so, just put it this way: `($lessons == "")`, since if its not set, you set it to `""`

Comment: The error is gone but now it brings me to create.php even when my table is already populated. It doesn't bring me to my k1levelselect.php

Comment: @Chunkeat so the problem really is not in this part of the code, but the one that checks whether the table is populated, you need to fetch from `select count(*) as total from table`, then get the count to check on your form condition

Comment: @Chunkeat wait, just a clarification, is `lessons` a table?

Comment: lessons is a column in a table called lessonno

Comment: @Chunkeat how many rows are there in this table? how are you going to check if `lessons` column is empty?

Comment: I am using if($lessons==null) to check if lessons is empty. If it's empty it'll bring me to create.php to add a row. Else it will go straight to k1levelselect.php to show the row that already exist.
There will only be one row in this table.

Comment: @Chunkeat no, you are checking it wrong, my edit should give an idea how to get it